# Python CGI URL Redirect

Tags: python, cgi

I am currently writing a CGI python script.  Once I have time I will rewrite this in `web2py`, but simply have no time ATM for this.

I have the whole logic built, except for one thing.  I need to be able to:

1) Send a variable to start a process (got that it works)
2) Refresh the page until such process ends
3) display information once process is done.

I can't seem to be able to get passed the URL refresh part, and stripping the variable which started the original process.

I tried webbrowser (`webbrowser.open('http://example.com?running=1')`), however for some reason I am not being redirected at all on Mac.

```
if print_html.parse_url():
    url_variable=print_html.parse_url()
    IP=url_variable['IP'].value
    Iterations=int(url_variable['quantity'].value)
    start=url_variable['start'].value
    refresh=url_variable['refresh'].value
if start == "1":
```

As you can see I read the variables from URL, and assign values.  When start == '1' I want to start running the rest of the programs. While the program is running I want to change the URL variable to re-read the page until everything is finished processing

Some more clarification, perhaps this helps:
 I need to refresh the page, or perhaps open the same page but with different variables.

For instance
1st instance: http://example.com/test.py?start=1
logic runs and then refresh spawning:
2st instance: http://example.com/test.py?running=1

Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but I believe I tried this and when I did it I *had* to open a new page or it never redirected properly. Pure python CGI is incredibly finicky.

Comment: `webbrowser` is for client functionality.

Comment: Please create a minimal, complete CGI program that demonstrates the problem you are having. Copy-paste that short program into your question.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606798/show-progress-of-python-cgi-script

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the page using the HTML [`meta http-equiv`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) directive.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime
import time

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print ""
print '''
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15" />
</head>'''

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = now.isoformat()

print '''
<body>
The time is now %s
</body>''' % now
```

Comment: Or, you know, since you output the headers yourself, just outputting the correct header.

Comment: True, but I chose to only mention one method so as not to muddy the water.

Comment: Thank you, but this won't work.  Refresh will also refresh all the variables which means that process will re-initialize. 
here is a snipped:
 if print_html.parse_url():
  url_variable=print_html.parse_url()
  IP=url_variable['IP'].value
  Iterations=int(url_variable['quantity'].value)
  start=url_variable['start'].value
  refresh=url_variable['refresh'].value
 if start == "1":

I made a function for my http headers, which does take arguments for refresh.  In this instance I want to avoid multiple spawning of same cgi page.

Comment: In that case, your requirements aren't clear. In the question, you write, "I need to be able to ... Refresh the page until such process ends". In your comment you write, " I want to avoid multiple spawning of same cgi page." These two requirements seem to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: That's the trick.  I need to both.  I need to refresh the page, or perhaps open the same page but with different variables.

For instance
1st instance: http://example.com/test.py?start=1
logic runs and then refresh spawning:
2st instance: http://example.com/test.py?running=1

Does that make sense?