# Python not flushing properly

Tags: python, apache, flush

I'm trying to flush content as it's generated by a Python script in a Linux server with apache. It's not working as expected. I generate this Test.py in order to make a proof of concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -u
from cgitb import enable
from time import sleep
from os import environ
import datetime
import sys

environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "true"

enable()
print("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8", flush=True)
print("", flush=True)
sys.stdout.flush()

print("<html><head>")
print("")
print("</head><body>")

Count=10
while (Count>0):
    print('Generated with print - at:'+str(datetime.datetime.now())+' and received at <script>document.write(Date());</script><br>', flush=True)
    sys.stdout.write('Generated with stdout - at:'+str(datetime.datetime.now())+' and received at <script>document.write(Date());</script><br>')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    Count=Count-1
    sleep(1)

print("</body></html>")
```

As you can see in the code, I'm trying all the techniques in order to get a nice flush, but all I get is:

```
Generated with print - at:2022-12-25 12:19:52 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with stdout - at:2022-12-25 12:19:52 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with print - at:2022-12-25 12:19:53 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with stdout - at:2022-12-25 12:19:53 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with print - at:2022-12-25 12:19:54 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with stdout - at:2022-12-25 12:19:54 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with print - at:2022-12-25 12:19:55 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with stdout - at:2022-12-25 12:19:55 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with print - at:2022-12-25 12:19:56 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with stdout - at:2022-12-25 12:19:56 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with print - at:2022-12-25 12:19:57 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with stdout - at:2022-12-25 12:19:57 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with print - at:2022-12-25 12:19:58 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with stdout - at:2022-12-25 12:19:58 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with print - at:2022-12-25 12:19:59 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with stdout - at:2022-12-25 12:19:59 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with print - at:2022-12-25 12:20:00 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with stdout - at:2022-12-25 12:20:00 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with print - at:2022-12-25 12:20:01 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
Generated with stdout - at:2022-12-25 12:20:01 and received at Sun Dec 25 2022 12:20:02
```

I really don't know how to proceed. Tried with chrome, firefox and edge on my windows client.

**EDIT**
I Add the properñy html tags as AKX asked for.

Comment: Setting PYTHONUNBUFFERED within the script itself does nothing, for one. You are also not sending a proper HTTP status line, so browsers are probably pretty confused.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "not working as expected" - what *did* you expect?

Comment: I assume the server waits until all the input is finished before executing any of the `<script>` contents.  I don't think this has anything to do with flush.

Comment: Added HTPP status line as @AKX pointed and problem persists.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it should flush a line to the navigator every second, not all of them at the end of the ten seconds.

Comment: @John\ Gordon <script> is opened and closed at every print. It's just to be able to compare both times, when the info i s writen by python and when its executed by the javascript in the navigator.

Comment: The "received at..." date is identical for all the output, which suggests that the server waited until the input was complete, and then executed all the scripts at once.

Comment: @John Gordon, at least the browser executes all at once, but server should send it one by one, because flush is present after every print and every stdout write.

Comment: That doesn't mean each line is _executed_ immediately as soon as it is received...

Comment: @John Gordon, how can I see each line appearing in my browser every second? How can I force to execute as they are received?

Comment: A HTML preamble is _not_ the `200 OK HTTP/1.0` status line you need to send. Please make sure you follow the HTTP spec.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is working properly: it prints the output every second.
So the question is: what do you expect?

If you want your web browser to show the progress of you script, read this:
[Show progress of PYTHON CGI script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606798/show-progress-of-python-cgi-script)